# I want to sort the two-way connection list in ascending order

Tags: c, arraylist, data-structures

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
}Node;

typedef struct arrlist {
    Node* head;
    Node* cur;
    Node* tail;
    Node* swap;
    Node* before;
}list;

void listinit(list* plist) {
    plist->head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    plist->tail = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    plist->head->prev = NULL;
    plist->head->next = plist->tail;
    plist->tail->next = NULL;
    plist->tail->prev = plist->head;
    plist->cur = NULL;
    plist->swap = NULL;
    plist->before = NULL;
}  
void listInsert(list* plist, int data) {
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = plist->head->next;
    newNode->prev = plist->tail->prev;
    plist->tail->prev->next = newNode;
    plist->tail->prev = newNode;
}
void linkedSwap(list* plist, int n) {
    Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    plist->before = plist->head->next;
    plist->cur = plist->before->next;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (plist->before->data >= plist->cur->data) {
                plist->before->next = plist->cur->next;
                plist->cur->prev = plist->before->prev;
                plist->cur->next->prev = plist->before;
                plist->cur->next = plist->before;
                plist->before->prev->next = plist->cur;
                plist->before->prev = plist->cur;
            }
            plist->before = plist->before->next;
            plist->cur = plist->cur->next;
        }
        plist->before = plist->head->next;
        plist->cur = plist->before->next;
    }
}
int listdisp(list* plist, int stop) {
    if (stop == 0) {
        plist->cur = plist->head->next;
        printf("%d ", plist->cur->data);
    }
    else {
        plist->cur = plist->cur->next;
        printf("%d ", plist->cur->data);
    }

}
```

The top code is one that excludes the main function. I want to output 1, 2, 3, 4 when I get inputs 4, 3, 2, 1, using the connection list, but I don't think it's a structural problem with the list output, and it's not because of the structural problems in the sorting function of the list ascending. Where the hell is the problem?

Comment: C is not C++. This looks more like C.

Comment: 1. Where is the rest of the program? 2. Too many pointers in `struct arrlist` 3. Why not insert in some order (ASC/DSC), so that he list is always sorted. Easy to display that.

Comment: Only the main function remains. Because sorting is the only goal, we didn't implement elements like deletion.